# C# Threadpool HttpClient Request

Tags: c#, httpclient, threadpool

I have a list of different urls.
These url I want to fetch with threadpooling.

I am using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method.
The problem here is I cannot pass an async httpclient call to this method as waitcallback. It needs to be synchronous. What is the best way realizing this?

Comment: you are mixing 2 things up, threadpool and async, choose one. To clarify, async will effectively parallelize your work for you using what it deems the best threads

Comment: @pm100 You can parallelize an asynchronous operation, but it's not *inherently parallel.  You can, and often do, write sequential asynchronous operations.  Additionally, something being asynchronous doesn't mean it's using other threads.  In fact, it usually doesn't.  This is a great example.  Querying a website's data doesn't require another thread to do work, it *doesn't require any thread to do work*.

Comment: You are member for four years and still don't learn how to create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? By the way, how this question is related with `python-requests`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev its not, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch each URL in parallel and asynchronously wait for them all to complete, you can just call `HttpClient.GetAsync` for each URL, then pass the tasks into `Task.WhenAll` to wait for them all to complete.

```
var urls = new[] { "http://google.com", "http://stackoverflow.com", "http://amazon.com" };
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
return Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(httpClient.GetAsync));
```